# Updating a column in a MySQL table based on some comparisons in another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm new to MySQL and need some help to achieve this result. My question goes as follows:

I have two tables A and B where table B is subset of table A.

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

Then, I add another column (say flag1 having default value 0) in table A.

I want to set value flag1=1 in table A where all the rows from table B are matching.

[image: Final Table]

How can I achieve this in MySQL? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    UPDATE TableA AS a
RIGHT JOIN TableB AS b
        ON a.col1 = b.col1
           AND a.col2 = b.col2
           AND a.col3 = b.col3
           AND a.col4 = b.col4
           AND a.col5 = b.col5
           AND a.col6 = b.col6
       SET a.flag1 = 1
```

The *Right Join* restricts the rows of TableA to the ones present in TableB and being identical on all six columns.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/650c74a)

Comment: wanted to ask, is this operation time taking? I'm asking this because my table consists of approximately 450,000 rows in table A and 160,000 rows in table B. It is taking quite a long time (waited for more than 15 mins) but didn't get any results.